# excel vba loop thru range and copy to single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a loop with Excel VBA, I have a data range in a1:a1000, I want to loop through them and copy one by one to single cell of C1, but below code not working, any idea what went wrong?

```
Dim I As Integer

For I = 1 To lastrow - 1
    Sheets("display").Range("w1").Value = Sheets("data").Range("c1").Offset(I, 0).Value              
    msgbox Sheets("data").Range("c1").Value    
Next I
```

Comment: you keep over writing the value in c1. You should add the new value to the old value as you go. Like for example myVariable  + cellValue

Comment: I was thinking to copy the data range from a1:a10 to single cell C1 when looping, is this correct ?

Comment: Well you'd have to sum the value of the range first but yes thats another approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the value in cell "W1" instead of "C1".

**Updated After Author's Clarification of Question:**

Below are two ways you can loop through cells and copy/paste. Neither one is "better". I would like to emphasize that there are probably more efficient methods than these to accomplish your task, but hopefully this answer gets you a resolution.

```
Sub LoopExampleUsingRange()
Dim aCell As Range

For Each aCell In Range("A1:A1000").Cells

aCell.Copy Range("C1")

Next aCell

End Sub

Sub LoopExampleUsingIntegerReference()
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 1000

Range("A" & i).Copy Range("C1")
'I prefer to use offset, but they both work: 
'Range("A1").Offset(i - 1, 0).Copy Range("C1")

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I want to use copy and paste method when looping through the data range, because some of the data are not numeric, what is the better way to do the loop?

Comment: @robin. Hopefully the updated answer works for you. I'd appreciate you checking off as a valid answer. Best of luck.

Comment: Hi PGCodeRider, thank you so much, both your codes are working! appreciate your time and sharing!